# Using standard e-mail address as user system wide name

Tags: user-accounts, ibm-domino

I'm going to re-build a very old Lotus Notes infrastructure coming from 4.x towards 8.5.

I'm trying to setup Domino so that all user names should be of a single string or the internet e-mail address.

For example the user "John Smith/ACME" should be in the whole system jsmith or jsmith@acme.com .

I still get jsmith/ACME all around.

Where it is most annoying is in the NAB when creating a new message. Is there a way to get all addresses in uniform standard e-mail adress format at least in mail ? The mixup in the destination like "John Smith/ACME, mjones@example.com" confused the users.

Answer (score 3):

That's how Domino handles domains, yes.

You can add a shortid (JSmith) or an email address (JSmith@acme.com) as other acceptable usernames for a given user, but you'll still have the username/domain all over the place because that's the fully qualified name for your users in Domino.